# stranger "may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]"

Tags: c++

Any idea? this is the log:

```
util.h: In function ‘bool BusyBees()’:
util.h:162:17: warning: ‘bestHashBee’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
 data[1] = x >> 8;
           ~~^~~~
miner.cpp:512:14: note: ‘bestHashBee’ was declared here
 uint32_t bestHashBee;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

this is util.h (the function declare):

```
/** Write a 32-bit unsigned little-endian integer. */
void inline WriteLE32(unsigned char *data, uint32_t x) {
data[0] = x;
data[1] = x >> 8;
data[2] = x >> 16;
data[3] = x >> 24;
}
```

this is where i use it:

```
uint32_t bestHashBee;
unsigned char beeNonceEncoded[4];
WriteLE32(beeNonceEncoded, bestHashBee);
std::vector<unsigned char> beeNonceVec(beeNonceEncoded, beeNonceEncoded + 4);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's clear from the compiler warning. You are not initializing the `bestHashBee` variable. You are just passing it to the `WriteLE32()` function and accessing it. But it contains garbage value.

Comment: The compiler told you where `bestHashBee` was declared and where it is used possibly before being initialized. Could you point out where you give `bestHashBee` a value between those two spots?

Comment: @linuxartisan i should do bestHashBee = 0 after use it on WriteLe32?

Comment: You have to give a value to `bestHashBee` _before_ trying to access it. You can't say `data[0] = x; ...` before initializing `bestHashBee`.

Comment: @linuxartisan i use it, i mean, i declare it, i use it (have a value) and then i use WriteLE32

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I am just trying to tell you that you need `bestHashBee = <some_int_here>;` statement *before* you call `WriteLE32(beeNonceEncoded, bestHashBee);`.

Comment: Declaring the primitive variable ‘bestHashBee’ does not give it any deterministic value. It may be 0, it may be garbage.

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani *"i declare it [`bestHashBee`], i use it (have a value) and then i use WriteLE32"* -- False. I see the line where you declare (and define) `bestHashBee`. I see the line where you use `WriteLE32`. The line in between does **not** use `bestHashBee`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the code:

```
uint32_t bestHashBee;
// at this point bestHashBee is an integer, but it could be any integer
// you have not told it what value it should have.  It might be 0 it might be
// 2879872.  It depends entirely on what was in that memory location before.
unsigned char beeNonceEncoded[4];
// beeNonceEncoded is an array of 4 random chars - they have not been
// initialized to any known value
WriteLE32(beeNonceEncoded, bestHashBee);
// now beeNonceEncoded contains 4 random chars.
std::vector<unsigned char> beeNonceVec(beeNonceEncoded, beeNonceEncoded + 4);

// you've passes bestHashBee to this function - it's a random value
void inline WriteLE32(unsigned char *data, uint32_t x) {
    data[0] = x;
// now data[0] contains a random value
//...
}
```

the compiler is warning you that you haven't initialized `bestHashbee` - it's unlikely that you want a slightly random value there.

The recommendations from all the commenters are:  initialize it.

```
uint32_t bestHashBee = 100;
```

would do it.  `100` might not be what you want either.  Depending on the version of c++ you're using, you could also use

```
uint32_t bestHashBee{100};
```